# Debugging GScript when called by Google App

Tags: debugging

I have written some GScript that is called by a Google App (Awesome Tables).

How do I debug the GScript while it is running (I particularly want to see that values in variables as I step through the code)?

Comment: If you have no code, you should start by writing some. For the time being, I suggest you copy this entire question and paste it to google.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the interface for Awesome Table, it doesn't seem it allows you to do that since you're running it on their server, and not the Google Server. If you find some way to do it on the Google Server, then as per usual just run scripts through the Script Editor with Logs or through debugging mode.

Sorry m8